# How can I restore many git submodules and tag the next version for release after reverting a parent repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules, revert

After reverting a repository state to yesterday's last commit (all commits today introduced too much instability), understadably all the submodules no longer point to commits made after their last tagged versions.

What is the correct way to tag the next release of these submodules?  I usually tag a version on the main branch for any module, but now that doesn't seem so straight forward.

Should I:

a)

- force each branch to point main at the previous commit?
  git branch -f main 1258f0d0aae
- and then tag another release?

b)
Or would I have to go and find some other way to ensure the state of the main branch for each submodule has a new commit applied that correctly reverts the changes?  I have many many submodules, If this is what is required I don't know how to do it efficiently.

c)
Something else I haven't considered entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Submodules don't have branches.

OK, that's too strong a claim.  Let's put it a different way: submodules don't *use* branches.

That's still a little too strong, but essentially accurate.  The fact is that the superproject Git manipulates each submodule Git.  In each submodule, it's the *superproject* that selects the submodule commit.

- It does this by storing a commit hash ID in a special entry called a *gitlink*.
- You check out some particular commit *in* the superproject, then you run `git submodule update --checkout` (or just `git submodule update`, or `git submodule update --init`, or any of these variants).  That uses the gitlink to do a *detached HEAD* checkout in the submodule.

So, once you have a superproject commit, it *already records the submodule hash IDs*.  There's nothing else to do other than run `git submodule update`.

If you want to make a *new* superproject commit, and record some *different* submodule hash ID for submodule `path/to/module`, you:

- enter the submodule;
- check out the target commit as a detached HEAD, or using a branch name, or whatever you like to pick the right commit; and last
- return to the superproject and run `git add path/to/module`.

This updates the *gitlink* entry in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, so that your next `git commit` records the desired commit hash ID for that submodule.

Hence, the answer to:

> What is the correct way to tag the next release of these submodules?

is to *do nothing*.  There is no tagging involved.

Comment: I've learnt a fair bit from your perspective, thanks for sharing.  The thing is though, the submodules are other projects (terraform projects).  They really do have branches in the way that they are maintained by other contributors (particularly the 'main' branch), which helps for collaboration between releases.  So if those branches are respected, if someone picks those up, then there would be a problem because the main branch is in a bad state.

Comment: @openCivilisation: Sure: each submodule is a Git repository in its own right. But that is independent of some superproject referring to it: the submodule has no knowledge of its use by N superprojects scattered around the globe. (That aside, there is the conceptual idea of N "reasonably closely related" Git projects, all using similar or identical branch and tag names. The Google "repo" command is meant for use with an idea like this. Git just fails to support it. There's an ongoing project to try to make Git support it, eventually, but I don't know if or when this might happen.)

Comment: How might you standardise operating in a team when dealing with errors?  Thinking out aloud... If we all took the latest tagged version to make changes to a module, then if there were problems in the latest release, the next release would be broken as well.  The same might go if they always worked off main.  But I guess if they worked off main, then fixes applied to main provide a means to fix things on the next merge / release.  Perhaps it's also possible so long as the tagged release is on main, then similar fixes are achievable regardless... Just figuring out methods to handle it in a team.

Comment: Release engineering is no simple topic but this sort of thing goes on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. :-)